# strings command printing some extra characters

Tags: mysql, string

I am trying to capture mysql traffic using tcpdump and converting it to text using `strings` command, but while capturing mysql traffic, I am getting some extra character at the end of each character. I am unable to figure out the reason.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE foo1.foo (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(20))H>
```

As you can see, there is `H>` at the end of query.
Can someone help me in solving this.

**Edit:** I am running the following command to capture the traffic.

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i any -s 0 -l -w - dst port 3306 | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 strings -12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mysql` protocol is not a text protocol, so strings and numbers expressed as binary will be exchanged. If the bytes making up the numbers appear to match printable characters in your locale, they will be displayed by `strings`.

Even if it were a *text* protocol, the query would be followed by the start of the next captured ethernet frame, with a pcap header that may very well contain byte values that match printable characters in your locale. Typically, the first 4 bytes of the pcap header is the time of the capture expressed as a 32bit number in the local endianness. For instance, the current Unix time is 0x51f65c79, which on a x86 PC would be stored as those bytes: 0x79 (ASCII `y`), 0x5c (ASCII backslash), 0xfc, 0x51 (ASCII `q`), which is probably what your seeing since in a MySQL `query` packet, the query text itself is what comes last.

Also bear in mind that long queries could be fragmented into several TCP packets and may contain characters that are not printable in your locale.

You should use something that is able to dissect the mysql protocol like `tshark`:

```
tshark -T fields -e 'mysql.query' -i any -R 'mysql.command == 3' tcp port mysql
```

That tells `tshark` to capture the TCP traffic on port 3306 (mysql) on `any` interface, filtering only mysql query traffic (`mysql.command == 3`), and outputting the `query` only.